# Change formating of a data frame (one to multiple column)

Tags: r

I have a pretty big data frame with the following content.

```
ID  lon     lat        species
1  8.94697 48.1015     sp1
2  8.94393 48.1007     sp1
3  8.94526 48.1031     sp2
4  8.94355 48.0977     sp2
5  8.94142 48.0985     sp1
6  8.94119 48.0980     sp3
7  8.94406 48.0954     sp4
```

But I want to transfrom the df to that:

```
ID   lon     lat         sp1   sp2   sp3   sp4
1  8.94697 48.1015      1     0     0     0
2  8.94393 48.1007      1     0     0     0
3  8.94526 48.1031      0     1     0     0
4  8.94355 48.0977      0     1     0     0
5  8.94142 48.0985      1     0     0     0
6  8.94119 48.0980      0     0     1     0
7  8.94406 48.0954      0     0     0     1
```

I have over 40 species in that table what would be good approach to transform the data frame?

Comment: Here is an alternative with the `nnet` package: `library(nnet)
df %>% cbind((class.ind(.$species) == 1)*1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`model.matrix` can help you here:

```r
cbind(df[1], as.data.frame(model.matrix(lm(ID ~ 0 + ., df))))
#>   ID     lon     lat speciessp1 speciessp2 speciessp3 speciessp4
#> 1  1 8.94697 48.1015          1          0          0          0
#> 2  2 8.94393 48.1007          1          0          0          0
#> 3  3 8.94526 48.1031          0          1          0          0
#> 4  4 8.94355 48.0977          0          1          0          0
#> 5  5 8.94142 48.0985          1          0          0          0
#> 6  6 8.94119 48.0980          0          0          1          0
#> 7  7 8.94406 48.0954          0          0          0          1
```

Or you could do

```r
cbind(df[1:3], sapply(unique(df$species), \(x) as.numeric(x == df$species)))
#>   ID     lon     lat sp1 sp2 sp3 sp4
#> 1  1 8.94697 48.1015   1   0   0   0
#> 2  2 8.94393 48.1007   1   0   0   0
#> 3  3 8.94526 48.1031   0   1   0   0
#> 4  4 8.94355 48.0977   0   1   0   0
#> 5  5 8.94142 48.0985   1   0   0   0
#> 6  6 8.94119 48.0980   0   0   1   0
#> 7  7 8.94406 48.0954   0   0   0   1
```

Having said that, think carefully about whether you actually need these dummy variables. Having a single column holding the same information as a factor makes your data easier to work with, and there aren't many instances where you need to have a set of dummy variables as opposed to a single factor variable. Without knowing your exact use case, it's hard to tell.